# Можно ли перенести информацию с Яндекс карт (рейтинг, средняя цена по заведению) на свой сайт

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Можете подсказать, хотим создать свой сайт и возник вопрос, можно ли с помощью yandex api добавить информацию на свой сайт (среднюю цену и рейтинги организаций)?

Comment: А есть какой-то ответ от поддержки Яндекс Бизнеса по этому вопросу? Ибо средняя цена - это уже не карты.

Answer (score 1):

Рейтинг вы можете добавить на сайт вместе с бейджем Бизнеса:

```html
<iframe src="https://yandex.ru/sprav/widget/rating-badge/8945440989" width="150" height="50" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Или одним из виджетов отзывов с Карт:

```html
    <iframe style="width:150px;height:98px;border:1px solid #e6e6e6;border-radius:8px;box-sizing:border-box" src="https://yandex.ru/maps-reviews-widget/8945440989"></iframe>
    
    <iframe style="width:200px;height:128px;border:1px solid #e6e6e6;border-radius:8px;box-sizing:border-box" src="https://yandex.ru/maps-reviews-widget/8945440989/?size=m"></iframe>
    
    <div style="width:350px;height:600px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;"><iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;border:1px solid #e6e6e6;border-radius:8px;box-sizing:border-box" src="https://yandex.ru/maps-reviews-widget/8945440989?comments"></iframe></div>
```